# swift/swiftui inheritance with opaque types

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a lot of different types of elements in an array, and I want them all to know how to understand how to render themselves... it's quite complex and I'm always adding new types - don't want to have to do shotgun surgery each time

but can't seem to work out the syntax for inheritance of a function with an opaque type return - if I do this:

```swift
class Element
{
   func forDisplay() -> some View 
   { fatalError("this function needs to be overridden")}
}
```

then try to override it

```
class TextElement : Element
{
    ...

    override func forDisplay() -> some View
    { return Text( self.textValue ) };
}
```

It gives me a compile error - and if I just leave out the word override

```
class TextElement : Element
{
    ...

    func forDisplay() -> some View
    { return Text( self.textValue ) };
}
```

it compiles fine, runs fine - but then calls the underlying error function

Comment: SwiftUI is Protocol based, not Inheritance based. `Element` should be a Protocol that the others adopt.

Comment: elements are complex things - 80% of the code is shared  - I don't see how I could use a protocol without duplicating that code

Comment: actually - I just tried it - and I can't even create a func that returns a view in a protocol - func for_display() -> View and func for_display() -> some View both don't work

Comment: How about composition over inheritance? You are going in the totally wrong direction here. If you insist on going in this direction, you might be better off using UIKit instead.

Comment: The protocol would need an associated type, and `forDisplay` would return that associated type.

Comment: actually - got it working by just not using opaque types - wrapping everything in AnyView and returning that works fine... just means lots of wrappers :(

Comment: Undo what you just did and use an associated type. AnyView will mess you up later in SwiftUI. You need to read up on Protocols.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Comment: The whole power of protocols is to share code via extensions. I strongly expect that what you're looking for is a protocol with an associated type as Sweeper notes. That's exactly the problem it exists to solve without creating wrappers. Class inheritance is very likely the wrong tool, but we'd need to see more explicitly what problem you're having using protocols with associated types. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID189

Comment: (Note that using protocols well often requires rethinking your patterns. It's not just "Java classes with another syntax." It's a very different approach to code sharing.)

Comment: In this case - I have many of the html elements covered - so when you create a h1 or h2 or h3 or h4 - you create with a text value, which gets stored and a shared constructor - but the only thing I have to override is the forDisplay function.  If I do it with protocols, I also have to duplicate the definition of the text variable and possibly the constructor - which is heaps more code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override opaque types. Better just to never subclass anything, really. It's a last resort. I bet you don't even want a reference type and you've only chosen a class because of inheritance, thinking it would model your solution well. Regardless…

Maybe you want a protocol with an associated type as has been recommended, or maybe you just want a generic `Element<View: SwiftUI.View>`. Trouble with those is, you won't be able to constrain extensions because you won't know what the opaque `Views` are. So I suspect you'll have more luck with phantom types.

```swift
protocol HeadingTag { }
enum H1: HeadingTag { }
enum H2: HeadingTag { }
enum H3: HeadingTag { }
```

```swift
class Element<Tag> {
```

```swift
extension Element where Tag: HeadingTag  {
  func forDisplay() -> some View {
    Text(textValue)
  }
}
```

```swift
extension Element where Tag == H2 {
  func forDisplay() -> some View {
    // An H2-specific view
```

Comment: interesting - will think about this - thanks